# Replace every second element in list with every third in other list.

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists.
Example:

```
a=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
b=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24]
```

Say I want to replace every second element in list a with every third element from list `b`.
For my purposes Im using this formula to do this for the first 2 respective elements:

```
a[1]="{}\n".format(b[2])
```

But how do I do this for all elements in the lists?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x,y in zip(range(1, len(a), 2), range(2, len(b), 3)):
    a[x] = '{}\n'.format(b[y])
```

Or, the short way, although this is a straight replacement and doesn't do your formatting:

```
a[1::2] = b[2::3]
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem!

Answer (score 7):

Use index slicing:

```
a = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
b = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24]
a[1::2] = b[2::3]
```

or if this formatting is also important:

```
a[1::2] = map('{}\n'.format, b[2::3])
```

Comment: This is really nice, but doesn't take care of the string formatting.

Comment: This worked too, needed the formatting so thank you!